# Is it possible to have duplicate HTTP GET query keys using Grape API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grape-api

I'm trying to create a custom REST API using Grape, but have hit a problem whereby I want to pass duplicate query string params for selected facets, such as

```
/search?fq=category:freezer&fq=brand:hotpoint.
```

The params object only has the last duplicate query value, so was wondering whether this was actually possible with Grape API?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: try `/search?fq[]=category:freezer&fq[]=brand:hotpoint`